# If $I_i$ are iid Bernoulli random variables, and I define $N_1 = \sum_{\{i:I_i=1\}} I_i$, how to find $E\left(\sum_{\{i:I_i=1\}} I_i\right)$?

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, binomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

If $I_1, \ldots, I_n$ are iid Bernoulli random variables with probability $p$, and I define $N_1 = \sum_{\{i:I_i=1\}} I_i$, i.e., the number of successes, then by what we know about the Binomial distribution, we should have that:

$$
E\left(N_1\right) = E\left(\sum_{\{i:I_i=1\}} I_i\right) = np
$$

However, what **bothers** me here is that $N_1$ is only summing through the indices corresponding to $I_i$ that are $1$. In that case, how do we still have the $n$ in the $np$?

Is there a way to think about it? I have a hunch I am **confusing** realized outcomes of a random variable v.s. the random variable itself. Should I be writing:

$$
E\left(N_1\right) = E\left(E\left(\sum_{\{i:I_i=1\}} I_i\right)\,\middle\vert\, \boldsymbol{I} = (I_1, \ldots, I_n)\right) 
$$

instead?

Comment: Surely it makes no difference whether or not you sum over the ones that are zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An equivalent definition is $N_1=\sum_{i=1}^n I_i$ because $\sum_{\{i:I_i=0\}} I_i = 0$. In this case:

$$E(N_1) = \sum_{i=1}^n E \left( I_i\right) = n E(I_1) = np $$

In the definition you gave, the number of the terms in the sum will depend on the result of each Bernoulli trial, so calculating the expected value is not as straight forward. Even though there may not be $n$ terms in that definition, $n$ still shows up in the result because it is being scaled by $p$. In other words, the expected number of terms in the sum is $np$ which is less than $n$.